# Need suggestion in Xamarin forms lazy loading with multiple sorting functionality

Tags: forms, listview, xamarin, loading, lazy-evaluation

we are working in an Xamarin mobile application. In that like every application we too have a list view which shows record from one particualr SQLite table let us say the table name as Loads.

View of the List has to satisfy few funtionality like

1. It needs to group the loads based on the Load date
2. It needs to sort the group list by Load date in descending order
3. In side the group load needs to sorted by Load time in descending if the load is not completed.
4. In side the group load needs to sorted by Load completion type in descending if the load is completed

To achieve the above said functionalities we wrote a logic and it was working fine when we try to load entire data from the Loads table.

Now we are trying to implement lazy loading for the list,so when we load the list with first set of 20 records these functionalities where working fine.

But when we scroll down the list we are loading the list with second set of 20 records and here comes the problem.In this case we are find difficulties in achieving the above said functionalities in the list view.

I would like to have the recommendation and approach like how handle this scenario.

Comment: please show the relevant code

Comment: The new CollectionView has this stuff built in. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data#load-data-incrementally

Comment: Could you provide the code about this problem "when we scroll down the list we are loading the list with second set of 20 records and here comes the problem"?